# How to use real quotation (citation) in PHP with variable?

Tags: php, html

I couldn't find an answer to my question. What I am trying to do, is as follows: I am trying to make sure that "the.. " and "them... " are quoted within this quote. It seems like using a variable makes it hard, though.

```
    $title = get_the_title();
    echo '<meta name="description" content= "Blabla some '.title.' here as well, but is it "the '.$title.'" or "them '.$title.'"?" />';
```

But what I see when I check my page source, is that it doesn't take the quotes as intended. I want to make sure that **"the [titlevariablehere]"** and **"them [titlevariablehere]"**, are actually outputted as citation marks and seen as part of the content.

How can I make this possible? I tried using backslashes, but still the same problem.

Comment: Just use `htmlspecialchars()` for your attribute values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not PHP, it's becuase the quotes are also the same as your surrounding quotes to define `content`.

So change the surrounding quotes like this:

```
 echo '<meta name="description" content=\'Blabla, but is it "the '.$title.'" or "them '.$title.'"?\' />';
```

Comment: Ah, great! I got it now. Thank you very much!